# dimmed screen while presenting alerts on iPhone X

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x

I was wondering if there is a way to remedy the following UI issue (pictured below). I find it peculiar that, when I present an alert, the area at the top by the notch is not also dimmed like the rest of the screen. Is this just the way iPhone X works and I can't do anything about it?

[image]

Comment: Are you doing anything special when presenting the alert? I just created a fresh Xcode project with an alert on the iPhone X simulator and the entire screen is dimmed.

Comment: Not any specific change for this should for iPhoneX. Make sure current controller on which you are presenting the alert view covers the top notch too..Otherwise it should work.